# click event propagation different in IE11 and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a table with a row of checkboxes.  I want the user to be able to check the checkbox by clicking anywhere in the cell containing the checkbox.

Which seems like a simple bit of jQuery:

```
td.click(function() {
    $(this).find("input").click();
}
```

My intent is that clicking in the cell triggers the click event on the checkbox. And that works, almost.

In IE11 and in Chrome, if I click in the cell, outside the checkbox, the checkbox is toggled, just as I want.

And in IE11, if I click inside the checkbox the checkbox is toggled. But if in Chrome, I click inside the checkbox, it looks like nothing happens.

Walking through this in the debuggers, it looks like my event handler is being called twice, in both IE and Chrome. And it looks like, when I check the checkbox, in Chrome, it's being checked in the first call and then unchecked in the second.  In IE11, the first time the checkbox is turned black, and in the second it is checked.

Given the two calls to the handler, I tried:

```
td.click(function(event) {
    var input = $(this).find("input");
    event.stopPropagation();
    input.click();
}
```

And that made no difference. The handler is still called twice.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when you click directly on the checkbox the event is also propagated to the table column.

So instead to stop the event propagatoin from within the column try to:

```
 $(function() {
        $('#tbl').find('td input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        })
        $('#tbl').find('td').click(function(e) {
            $(this).find("input").click();
        });
    });
```

Hope it could be usefull.

Comment: I'd been trying to stop propagation on the td, instead of on the input.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because clicking the checkbox is also registered as a click on the td. IE's handling of it is incorrect in my opinion, but that's not really important here.

I would simply change the checked property instead of triggering the click event. I would also base my selection on the event target so that it won't target the checkbox if it's the one clicked.

```
td.click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).find("input").prop('checked', function (i, propValue) {
        return !propValue;
    });
});
```